# How does HTTP/2 provide faster browsing speed compared to HTTP/1.1?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, multiplexing, http2

I was reading reading an [article](http://thehackernews.com/2015/02/http2-fast-websites.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheHackersNews%20%28The%20Hackers%20News%20-%20Security%20Blog%29&_m=3n.009a.858.gd0ao075d9.hty) on launching of HTTP/2. It was said that HTTP/2 is based on SPDY (speedy) protocol and it can provide faster browsing speed compared to HTTP/1.1 by using  "header field compression" and "multiplexing". How does these terms exactly work?

Am I supposed to believe that in HTTP/1.1 requests are processed in a  'one after the other' manner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Multiplexing**

With HTTP 1.1 a lot of time is spent just waiting. A browser sends requests and waits for the response to come back and then sends another GET etc. An inefficient use of the bandwidth. At times it would use Pipelining but that too suffers that sometimes requests need to wait for the requests done prior. The head of line blocking problem.

With multiplexing, there's virtually no waiting but the browsers can just ask for hundreds of things at once and they will be delivered in whatever order they can be delivered and without individual streams or objects having to wait for each other. (With prioritization and flow control to help control them properly.)

This will be most notable on high-latency connections. For a visible and clear demo what it can do, see the golang's gophertiles demo at https://http2.golang.org/gophertiles?latency=1000 (requires a HTTP/2 enabled browser)

**Header compression**

Additionally, HTTP/2 offers header compression that makes a client able to squeeze in more requests earlier in a TCP connection lifetime. In the early slow-start period of a new TCP connection it can be valuable to cram in more requests so that the responses come back earlier. HTTP headers are extremely repetitive in their nature.

**Server push**

A HTTP/2 server can send data to the client *as if the client asked for it*, before the client asks for it! If the server thinks the client is likely to want/need that too, and thus a half RTT can be saved.

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for :)`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with HTTP/2, both headers and HTTP response content could be compressed. With HTTP/1.1, headers are never compressed contrary to the content (specified with Content-Encoding header).

Multiplexing is related to server-push. Actually, when the server sends an HTML page, it can use the same connection to push additional resources like css and javascript files. If the HTML page needs to load those additional scripts, no more request will be sent to the server as they were already sent previously.

Comment: Most compression algorithm are deflate and gzip but technically the protocol allows to specify any other method because you explicitely indicate which one is used in the Content-Encoding header).

Comment: Multiplexing is not really about server-push. It is about allow several simultaneous transfers at once.